# Guidance on optimal matching algorthims

Tags: time-series, optimization, matching

I'm working with a data set of automated radio-telemetry recordings from birds and other animals. I need to match time-stamped records from multiple sources to their nearest neighbor and I'm looking for some suggestions on how to proceed.

We have a system of towers that can record the signal strength from a transmitter every 3-12 minutes (it varies). However, the towers aren't perfectly in sync when they record data for a given frequency, so one tower might log an observation at 14:22:09 while another logs that same frequency at 14:22:13. Typically, we try and use the recordings from multiple towers to biangulate or triangulate an animal's location. If the time gap is too large (the threshold varies with species) we will throw out that tower record.

If I were to select one record from each tower, here is what a matrix of time lags of records might look like

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
A   0   0   0   5   3   7
B       0   0   5   3   7
C           0   5   3   7
D               0   2   2
E                   0   4
F                       0
```

Because frequencies are scanned in cycles, the lags within a cycle are much, much smaller than the time between cycles.

In the past, we've rounded time stamps for each record to some threshold, such 4 seconds. In the above case, that leads to estimation using only ABCE. D and F are deleted. I'm wondering if there is an algorithm that will allow me to create optimal matches for each cycle. Effectively, this would create a match between ABCE, with one time index, and another match between DEF with a different time index.

Right now I'm just looking for some suggestions for tools or techniques to apply. If it's something already existing in R all the better, but I'd be happy with a book reference too.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your question. However, one approach that might be relevant is [kalman filtering](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/kalman-filter/info), which is used to account for sensor noise in [target tracking](https://www.google.com/#q=kalman+filter+target+tracking).

Comment: I don't think it's a case for Kalman filtering. I'm trying to match the records among towers closest in time to one another. Rather than delete records outside some time threshold, I'd like to make new matches, even if it means some individual records from individual towers appear in more than one than one match

Comment: OK. Kalman filtering lets you incorporate a predicted trajectory based on velocity. I was thinking that if you "create a match between ABCE, with one time index, and another match between DEF with a different time index", then this would give 2 positions at 2 times, so this would imply a velocity. If you have 3 positions at 3 times, the Kalman filter is a standard way to combine uncertainty in 1) your measurements, 2) the implied locations and velocities, and 3) predicted position from previous location and velocity. This may not apply in your case though.

Comment: A sliding window might be useful in addition to your initial 4 second interval  where you keep progressing this window in increments of a second but approximate readings for next 4 seconds.